# Parsing a json Object by Xpath using JXPathContext/java

Tags: java, json, xpath

I want to parse a json object by xpath in java.I have tried in the following way:

```js
  JSONObject  obj=new JSONObject("{\"firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"doe\",\"age\":26,\"address\":{\"streetAddress\":\"naiststreet\",\"city\":\"Nara\",\"postalCode\":\"630-0192\"},\"phoneNumbers\":[{\"type\":\"iPhone\",\"number\":\"0123-4567-8888\"},{\"type\":\"home\",\"number\":\"0123-4567-8910\"}]}");

        JXPathContext context = JXPathContext .newContext(obj);
        Iterator i=context.iterate("phoneNumbers[0]/type");
```

But i found out that the above way is not working as the Iterator doesnt contain  anything.
Can anyone please let me know whether I am doing any mistake here?
Also,can anyone please let  me know if there is any other better way of parsing a json object by xpath.

Comment: Is this about XPath or JsonPath?

Comment: xpath would be better.But With JsonPath would also be fine.

Comment: I don't know that API but with XPath the index starts with `1`, not with `0` so assuming XPath conventions the path should be `phoneNumbers[1]/type`.

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted in comment, the XPath is wrong due to indexes starting with 1.

The second trick is to call "toMap" on your JSONObject.
JXPath doesn't know how to deal with JSONObject, but can deal with maps.

```java
JSONObject  obj=new JSONObject("{\"firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"doe\",\"age\":26,\"address\":{\"streetAddress\":\"naiststreet\",\"city\":\"Nara\",\"postalCode\":\"630-0192\"},\"phoneNumbers\":[{\"type\":\"iPhone\",\"number\":\"0123-4567-8888\"},{\"type\":\"home\",\"number\":\"0123-4567-8910\"}]}");

JXPathContext context = JXPathContext .newContext(obj.toMap());
Iterator i=context.iterate("phoneNumbers[1]/type");
```